# VB.net sample of MicrosoftGraph?

Tags: ms-office, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking for a VB.Net sample of using Microsoft Graph (connecting to Office 365 API online)?

All samples I can find is in C#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: MojoDK.....did you find any VB.NET sample code? :-)

Comment: @MrCalvin nope I gave up - even used a MSDN support ticket with Microsoft, but they couldn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. At present we do not have any VB.NET samples that work with Microsoft Graph. We will take your question and other feedback we are getting into account as we prioritize languages and platforms for our next samples.